# Merging Multiple SQL statements into one

Tags: sql, sql-server, sapb1

I have used the following SQL statement in Sap b1, to get information based on the component information.

it works/ i can get the data and work fine but it looks like this code affects the performance, it slows down when navigating between records.

what is the best way to make this perform better?

```
  @STORE1 = SQL(SELECT T2."U_LoadPSI" FROM "A_SANDBOX"."ITT1"  T1 Inner Join OITM T2 on T2."ItemCode" = T1."Code" WHERE T1."Father" = $[$5.0.0] and  T1."Code"  LIKE '20%'); 
IF (@STORE1 !='') 
BEGIN  
Set($[$BOYX_80.0.0]|@STORE1); 
END 
ELSE 
BEGIN  
Set($[$BOYX_80.0.0]|''); 
END

    @STORE2 = SQL(SELECT T2."U_LoadLbs" FROM "A_SANDBOX"."ITT1"  T1 Inner Join OITM T2 on T2."ItemCode" = T1."Code" WHERE T1."Father" = $[$5.0.0] and  T1."Code"  LIKE '20%'); 
IF (@STORE2 !='') 
BEGIN  
Set($[$BOYX_81.0.0]|@STORE2); 
END 
ELSE 
BEGIN  
Set($[$BOYX_81.0.0]|''); 
END

    @STORE3 = SQL(SELECT T2."U_TireSize" FROM "A_SANDBOX"."ITT1"  T1 Inner Join OITM T2 on T2."ItemCode" = T1."Code" WHERE T1."Father" = $[$5.0.0] and  T1."Code"  LIKE '20%'); 
IF (@STORE3 !='') 
BEGIN 
Set($[$BOYX_38.0.0]|@STORE3); 
END 
ELSE 
BEGIN  
Set($[$BOYX_38.0.0]|''); 
END

    @STORE4 = SQL(SELECT T2."U_Size" FROM "A_SANDBOX"."ITT1"  T1 Inner Join OITM T2 on T2."ItemCode" = T1."Code" WHERE T1."Father" = $[$5.0.0] and  T1."Code"  LIKE '50%' ); 
IF (@STORE4 !='') 
BEGIN 
Set($[$BOYX_39.0.0]|@STORE4); 
END 
ELSE 
BEGIN  
Set($[$BOYX_39.0.0]|''); 
END

    @STORE5 = SQL(SELECT T2."U_Color" FROM "A_SANDBOX"."ITT1"  T1 Inner Join OITM T2 on T2."ItemCode" = T1."Code" WHERE T1."Father" = $[$5.0.0] and  T1."Code"  LIKE '50%'); 
IF (@STORE5 !='') 
BEGIN 
Set($[$BOYX_82.0.0]|@STORE5); 
END 
ELSE 
BEGIN  
Set($[$BOYX_82.0.0]|''); 
END
```

Comment: What is the language of **whole** script? `Set($[$BOYX_39.0.0]|@STORE4)` obviously not T-SQL. Is it VB/VB.NET/something other?

Comment: @Ingaz its called SAP add-on called Boyum Set($[$BOYX_39.0.0]|@STORE4) sets the value of STORE4 in [$BOYX_39.0.0] its a text box